# Move hyperref anchor link in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

In the example below, the title of the starred section is moved to the left in the TOC but not the corresponding hyperref anchor link:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{-1cm}Introduction}
\section{Title}
\end{document}
```

How is it possible to move it as well?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formattting of the entry in the table of contents for sections are controlled by macro `\l@section`. The following example defines `\l@leftsection` that puts the entry 1cm to the left. `\toclevel@leftsection` defines the level number for the bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\l@leftsection\l@section
\let\toclevel@leftsection\toclevel@section
\patchcmd\l@leftsection{\hskip}{\kern-1cm\hskip}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{leftsection}{Introduction}
\section{Title}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]